# Windows GPO "set user home folder" adds domain name to home folder

Tags: group-policy, home-directory

I set a GPO to 'Set user home folder', use H: and as path '\fileserver\root\Home'.

This works as expected, but the home folder that created is like this;

\fileserver\root\Home\johndoe.domainname\

And I wonder why the '.domainname' is added to the folder.

Since this policy is in a domain in a subforest, so I think that's why the domain name is added to the folder, but I'd like an official statement from Microsoft confirming this. Can't seem to find it.

So far I found: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649079(v=ws.11).aspx

> A user's home folder, if configured, is the default folder used by some programs such as Windows PowerShell. You can configure an alternative local or network location on a per-user basis by using the Home folder section of the user account properties in AD DS. To configure the home folder location for all users of a computer running Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012 R2, or Windows Server 2012 in a virtual desktop environment, enable the Set user home folder policy setting, and then specify the file share and drive letter to map (or specify a local folder). Do not use environment variables or ellipses. The user’s alias is appended to the end of the path specified during user sign on.

Microsoft says it's the user's alias thats added...?